# Loop not getting the same value as the printed one

Tags: python

First of all, the error I'm getting might be really basic, but I couldn't solve it so I decided to reach for some help.

The original program is a long one, but I reproduced the error on a short one which is the following :

```
def list_maker():

    game_list = []
    game_list += [[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f']]]
    
    move_counter = 1

    while move_counter <= 5:
        after_move_list = game_list[move_counter - 1]
        
        after_move_list[0][0] = str(move_counter)
            
        print(after_move_list, '\n')
        game_list += [after_move_list]
        
        move_counter += 1
    
    return game_list
```

The problem I'm facing is about the output. Indeed, the output is the following

```
[['1', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] 

[['2', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] 

[['3', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] 

[['4', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] 

[['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] 

Out[30]: 
[[['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
 [['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
 [['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
 [['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
 [['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
 [['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]]
```

While I want the values of the returned list to be the same as the ones printed above.

Thank you in advance to anyone who will take the time to read.

Comment: what is your expected output & actual output. Please clear in question

Comment: You are continually referencing the same list. I think that you think that assignment is the same as copying. Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a new list each time round the loop:

```py
def list_maker():
    game_list = []
    
    move_counter = 1
    while move_counter <= 5:
        after_move_list = [[str(move_counter), 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f']]
        
        game_list += [after_move_list]
        
        move_counter += 1
    
    return game_list

print(list_maker())
```

Output:

```
[[['1', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['2', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['3', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['4', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others your issue is you kept appending the original list rather than copies of it i.e. you kept appending this original object:

`[[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f']]]`

placed at `game_list[0]`.

Another solution is to use deepcopy to make copies by changing the append line from:

```
game_list += [after_move_list]
```

To:

```
game_list += [deepcopy(after_move_list)]
```

**Complete Code**

```
from copy import deepcopy

def list_maker():

    game_list = []
    game_list += [[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f']]]
    
    move_counter = 1

    while move_counter <= 5:
        after_move_list = game_list[move_counter - 1]   # accesing last list in game list (i.e. top of stack)
        
        after_move_list[0][0] = str(move_counter)       # changing list at top of stack
            
        print(after_move_list, len(game_list))          # print modified list at top of stack
        game_list += [deepcopy(after_move_list)]        # Push copy of last list onto stack
        
        move_counter += 1
    
    return game_list

list_maker()
```

**More Pythonic Version**

```
def list_maker():
    game_list = [[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f']] for _ in range(5)]
    
    for index, game in enumerate(game_list, start=1):
        game[0][0] = str(index)
        print(game)
        
    return game_list
    
list_maker()
```

**Output (both versions)**

Prints:

```
[['1', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] 

[['2', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] 

[['3', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] 

[['4', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] 

[['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Out:

```
[[['1', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
 [['2', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
 [['3', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
 [['4', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
 [['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
 [['5', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]]
```